# how to display group name in android

Tags: java, android

hi in the below code I am calling method `imService.DispalyGroupDetails(imService.getUsername());` what I am trying to accessing means I am passing parameter imService.getUsername() it will return the username based on username I am sending the request to server from that I am getting groupname.

My Problem is it's printing the groupdetails 0 why I am getting 0 I am not getting.can any one help me from this issue.

**java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
        setContentView(R.layout.list_screen);

        friendAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(this);



        try {
            imService=Login.imService;
            String groupdetails = imService.DispalyGroupDetails(imService.getUsername());   
            System.out.println(groupdetails);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**java**

```
public String DispalyGroupDetails(String username) throws UnsupportedEncodingException  {


            String params = 
                        "username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") + 
                        "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") +
                        "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("DispalyGroupFDetails","UTF-8")+
                        "&";

            Log.i("PARAMS", params);
            return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);              

    }
```

Comment: What response getting `System.out.println(groupdetails);` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK response From this line 0

Comment: `My Problem is it's printing the groupdetails 0 why I am getting 0 I am not getting` line clear to me what you want to say?

Comment: I want display the group name for example String

Comment: you are getting `0` from server what is issue show `0` as group name. you are trying to do this task from yesterday

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it will return 1

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK From server I am returning 0 means FAILED and SUCCESFUL means I want to return 1

Comment: from the server it's returning 1

Comment: you are sending `Log.i("PARAMS", params);` params with url. so try same in browser using HTTPPoster or poster plugins and check getting same result

Comment: use `String response=socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);
 Log.i("response", "response ::"+response);
return response;`  and check what you are getting from server

Comment: params giving username=user2&password=user2&action=DispalyGroupFDetails& this is the output

Comment: :: what you are getting `Log.i("response", "response ::"+response);` line?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK response ::0

Comment: then why you are saying getting `1` from server ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK My problem got solved I gave wrong action name

Comment: great work by you and `user1`.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK both are same